# Arguments isn't passed on correctly to function in R

Tags: r, function

I've written my first function, but it's not working. I get the error:  Error: Column `var1` is unknown 
when running the function.

Edit: the code below is part of a bigger chunk of code that also produces the graph, but that part works.

Code:

```
# Creating dummydata
a <- sample(letters[1:5], 500, rep = TRUE)
b <- sample(1:10, 500, rep = TRUE)
df1 <- data.frame(a, b)

create_barchart <- function(data, var1, var2) {
  # Creating summary statistics
  df <- data %>%
    group_by(var1, var2) %>%
    summarise(n=n()) %>%
    group_by(var1) %>%
    mutate(perc=100*n/sum(n))
}

create_barchart(df1, a, b)
```

Comment: Is it just an open-brace `{` you're missing, or is there more we don't see?

Comment: To do that, you need to look at non-standard evaluation (NSE) for `dplyr` verbs. Suggested start https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html, though web-searching for `dplyr nse` should provide several good examples.

Comment: @r2evans: it was a paste-miss by me, it's there in the function. I've corrected the code 

I'll look into NSE, thanks.

Comment: It's worth noting that the second `group_by()` in the function is unnecessary.  `summarise()` will remove the last grouping level and what is returned is still grouped by `var1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put {{...}} around `var1` and `var2` and remove `df <-`.  Suggest you use `ungroup` to terminate the `group_by`.

Also note that `count({{var1}}, {{var2}})` could be used in place of `group_by({{var1}}, {{var2}}) %>% summarize(n = n()) %>% ungroup` .

```
library(dplyr)

create_barchart <- function(data, var1, var2) {
  # Creating summary statistics
  data %>%
    group_by({{var1}}, {{var2}}) %>%
    summarise(n=n()) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    group_by({{var1}}) %>%
    mutate(perc=100*n/sum(n)) %>%
    ungroup
}

create_barchart(df1, a, b)
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. As mentioned in my edit, it's just part of a larger function that includes ggplot, so the function is correctly named.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to Grothendieck's answer, you can use the `enquo()`-`!!` (pronounced as "Bang Bang") pair

```
create_barchart <- function(data, var1, var2) {
  var1 <- enquo(var1)
  var2 <- enquo(var2)
  # Creating summary statistics
  df <- data %>%
    group_by(!!var1, !!var2) %>%
    summarise(n=n()) %>%
    group_by(!!var1) %>%
    mutate(perc=100*n/sum(n))
  return(df)
}

create_barchart(data = df1, var1 = a, var2 = b)
```

For a more in depth explanation you can also see this [blog post](https://www.statworx.com/de/blog/bang-bang-how-to-program-with-dplyr/).